# remove comma from a specific portion of a long string

Tags: text-processing

I have document contain very long strings represent decoded information, i want to remove `,` commas from the last portion of the string. For example this is one of the long strings:

```
 Insert into PE_ATRT_S(ID_ANA_TX,FQ_WQ_ASDF,ID_PRTY,NM_ATHY_TX,SC_RND,QU_DGT_RND) values (99990987868959,null,68,'T59 - %,Dsc,Itm-2 tax 1 Juris',4,5);
```

I want to remove comma from the last portion of it so let me zoom in to show you how it look like:

```
(99990987868959,null,68,'T59 - %,Dsc,Itm-2 tax 1 Juris',4,5);
```

so the final result look like this:

```
Insert into PE_ATRT_S(ID_ANA_TX,FQ_WQ_ASDF,ID_PRTY,NM_ATHY_TX,SC_RND,QU_DGT_RND) values (99990987868959,null,68,'T59 - % Dsc Itm-2 tax 1 Juris',4,5);
```

please notice the last portion of the long string, no comma in part of it let's zoom in to see it better:

```
(99990987868959,null,68,'T59 - % Dsc Itm-2 tax 1 Juris',4,5);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
awk -F\' -vOFS=\' '{gsub(","," ",$2); print}'
```

Comment: Nice solution. Just one bug : it will work only with lines having one `'...,...'` field.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou This solution can be made more general: `awk -F\' -vOFS=\' '{for(n=1;n<=NF;n++){if(n%2==0){gsub(","," ",$n)}} print}'`.

Comment: @simlev: You can omit the filter on the iteration counter if you adjust the iteration start and step size: `for (n = 2; n <= NF; n += 2) gsub(",", " ", $n);`

Answer (score 3):

Alternative solution with `gnu sed`:

```
sed -r 's/(\x27.*),(.*\x27)/\1 \2/g' file
```

`\x27` : ascii code of single quote `'`

Comment: Nice way of working around `'`, but this removes only the last of the commas inside the single quotes, giving `%,Dsc ` instead of `% Dsc ` as was requested by the OP. I solved this issue using recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Perl showcase:

```
perl -pe "1 while s/'.*\K,(?=.*')/ /" input.txt
```

Output:

```
Insert into PE_ATRT_S(ID_ANA_TX,FQ_WQ_ASDF,ID_PRTY,NM_ATHY_TX,SC_RND,QU_DGT_RND) values (99990987868959,null,68,'T59 - % Dsc Itm-2 tax 1 Juris',4,5);
```

Zoomed output:

```
(99990987868959,null,68,'T59 - % Dsc Itm-2 tax 1 Juris',4,5);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 perl -pe "s/.*'\K(.*?)(?=')/\$1 =~ y|,| |r/e"
```

- Skip to the last pair of single quotes by means of greedy regex .*
- Then select the content in between the single quotes and transform all comnas to spaces.